# Parallel or incident lines?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given the line $r$ with the Cartesian equation $3x+ 2y + 7 = 0$, and the line $s$ with parametric equations:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x=2+3t \\ 
y=1+3t \\
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

with $t ∈ \mathbb{R}$. How can I find if $r$ and $s$ are parallel or incident, and in the latter case how can I find the coordinates of the intersection point? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

A possible method is to convert the second in cartesian coordinates

$$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x=2+3t \\ 
y=1+3t \\
\end{array}
\right.\iff y=1+x-2\iff y=x-1$$
Now consider the system

$\begin{cases}y=x-1\\3x+ 2y + 7 = 0\end{cases}\implies3x+2(x-1)+7=0\implies5x+5=0 \implies...$

Comment: How did you convert it into cartesian coordinates? Show more passages please

Comment: @user530111 it'easy, from the first $3t=x-2$ then substitute 3t in the second

Comment: So they're incident and their intersection point is $P(-1,-2)$ ?

Comment: @user530111 Yes exactly!